# iPhone Mail Making Table Gap (Pseudo Line Break) Really Big

Tags: iphone, email, html-email

I'm having an issue where the following code displays fine everywhere, but gets interpreted by mail on an iPhone as a massive vertical space. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Andy.

```
<!-- 20px Spacer -->
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD height=20>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following works for cross client vertical spaces:

```
<td height="20" style="height:20px;">
<div style="height:20px;width:1px;"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you expect the signature to have multiple tables, or one big table?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, but I have coded up emails that are composed of a few tables and also ones that have so many nested tables that it becomes very confusing making any changes.

Comment: Perhaps on iPhone, but I've found that the div with specified height is necessary for a specified height in Gmail.